# Why isn't this lodash uniq isSorted not working?

Tags: javascript, lodash

So, I would expect this to sort, but it isn't.

```
_.uniq(array, [isSorted], [iteratee], [thisArg])
```

so

```
_.uniq([10,3,13,1,0,2], true);
```

I run that, and it doesn't sort. I'd expect it to return: [0,1,2,3,10,13]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not what the `isSorted` parameter does.

> [isSorted] (boolean): Specify the array is sorted. -
>   https://lodash.com/docs#uniq

does not mean it will also sort the array for you but that if you set it to true then it's expecting an already sorted array.

> Providing true for isSorted performs a faster search algorithm for sorted arrays.

It's an optimization in that the algorithm for "Creates a duplicate-free version of an array" is a lot faster if the array is already sorted.